# HTML button isn’t showing up

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, I’m new to all this, and this is a test website, and I’ve been searching the web for solutions for like an hour. This button in html isn’t showing up even though I used the right tags and stuff… is there a piece of code I need to input to import JavaScript or something? I know  is a thing but I’ve seen people put it inside the tags like I did. I don’t know what I’m doing wrong.

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
<head><h1>Do you like pineapple on pizza?</h1></head><br>
<body> 
<label for="pizza-select">Tell the truth. C'mon...</label>
<select id="pizza-select">
<option value= "">Pick one goddamn it.</option>
<option value= "yes">Yes, I feel special for having an unpopular opinion</option>
<option value= "no">No, I am close minded and hate having fun</option> <br>
<button onclick="alert('eh idc')">Done</button>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing the `select` closing tag.

Comment: You cannot have `<h1>` in the `<head>`.

Comment: It’s working now thanks :D I should be more observant next time

Comment: You cannot have any other HTML elements as children of `html` other than `head` and `body`. (you have `br`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Main problem**

Looks like you forgot to close your `select` tag which is the root of your `button` issue.

**Further notes**

Using an `h1` in the `head` is not allowed, and will not work. If you are looking for a tab/page title I would recommend using the `<title>` tag as shown below. You can use the `h1` as your content headline, but make sure to keep it in your `body`.

```html
<!doctype html>
<HTML> 

<head>
<title>Do you like pineapple on pizza?</title>
</head>

<body> 
<h1>Do you like pineapple on pizza?</h1>
<label for="pizza-select">Tell the truth. C'mon...</label>
<select id="pizza-select">
<option value= "">Pick one goddamn it.</option>
<option value= "yes">Yes, I feel special for having an unpopular opinion</option>
<option value= "no">No, I am close minded and hate having fun</option>
</select>
<br>
<button onclick="alert('eh idc')">Done</button>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the `select` tag:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html> 
<head><h1>Do you like pineapple on pizza?</h1></head><br>
<body> 
<label for="pizza-select">Tell the truth. C'mon...</label>
<select id="pizza-select">
<option value= "">Pick one goddamn it.</option>
<option value= "yes">Yes, I feel special for having an unpopular opinion</option>
<option value= "no">No, I am close minded and hate having fun</option>
</select>
<br>

<button onclick="alert('eh idc')">Done</button>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: `h1` is not allowed in `head`. `br` is not allowed in `html`.

Answer (score -1):

Every thing good as now. you don't need to add head you can directly add text into body or add with heading tags

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<title>Pizza</title>
<body>
<h1>Do you like pineapple on pizza?</h1><br>
<label for="pizza-select">Tell the truth. C'mon...</label>
<select id="pizza-select">
<option value= "">Pick one goddamn it.</option>
<option value= "yes">Yes, I feel special for having an unpopular opinion</option>
<option value= "no">No, I am close minded and hate having fun</option>
</select>
<br>

<button onclick="alert('eh idc')">Done</button>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: `title` tag must be a child of `head`, which your code doesn't have at all.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).